# How to add Emoji button to my website using just vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, emoji

I'm working on my first project and what i want to do is add Emoji set to my website . want  i want to have is clicking on a certain buttons with the same class something like id=emoji , will trigger a window with full set of emoji, tried fetching an API and I pushed all the raw data to an Array but to be honest i don't know how to make it show up in a window like so I tried to use a package emoji-button but it keep giving me the error

> Loading module from “http://127.0.0.1:5500/node_modules/@joeattardi/emoji-button/” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”).

I tried to change the type from Module to text/javascript it's doesn't give me the error , no errors show up , but instead when i click the button nothing happen..

```js
import EmojiButton from './node_modules/@joeattardi/emoji-button';

  const button = document.querySelector('#emoji-button');
  const picker = new EmojiButton();

  picker.on('emoji', emoji => {
    document.querySelector('input').value += emoji;
  });

  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    picker.togglePicker(button);
  });
```

```html
<div>
<input type="emoji">
<button id="emoji-button"></button>
</div>

<script src="Emoji.js" type="module"></script>
```

Comment: The error you are getting indicates that your server is not properly serving the correct MIME types for the script. The MIME type is required to be correct for modules, but is mostly ignored for "normal" scripts (which is a security hazard - that's why it's required to be correct for newer standards)

Comment: Also, when you fix this, you'll have to change your import to `{EmojiButton}` (because it's a named export)

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol  have no idea what your talking about i just started coding like 6 months ago still have no clue about a lot of things .... "-,-